# Is there a way to move the pivot point directly of any selection

Tags: 3d-cursor

Is there any way to move the pivot/scaling point of a selection (not an object) directly? I've moved from Maya and the closest equivilent I can find is the 3d cursor, which requires a lot of extra steps compared to Maya which lets you detach and move the pivot point like it's own object.

Thanks.

Comment: 3D Cursor can be relocated with Cursor tool or [Shift+RMB] when other tool is activiated. Snapping setting also affecting this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for that, it's a bit hidden: 
[image]

upper right of the Viewport.

That would change the actual origin, though. If you want to temporarily do that, parenting and the 3D cursor are the only options I can think of. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The problem is that only works for objects, not selections of an object. I work a lot with mirroring, and I scale parts of the mesh, and this often means it disrupts the mirror seam, so I have to manually fix it, I really need a way to quickly shift the pivot to the mirror line so I don't have to do that.

Comment: By selections of an object you mean vertices? I also don't know what a mirror seam is. The easiest way in my eyes would be to work with SHIFT S Snap cursor. Either to object origin, one of the centered vertices that's part of the mirror plane etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think I've struggled to explain the issue properly, however I did get to a solution eventually.